# template logic not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

template is

```
{% for type in types %} <h1>{{type.title}}</h1>

   {% for field in typelist %}
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{field}}">{{ field }}</label><br />
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %} <br />
```

model.py

```
class Types(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    parent_type_id = models.CharField('Parent Type', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)
```

Here below this variable `{{type.title}}` is Bus and variable `{{ field }}` as a.Seat and b.Glass,

In my case,if 1.Bus is parent element and their child element are a.seat b.Glass and same way  2.Classroom,their child elements are a.Blackboard b.Table etc.

So using the above loop is gives the output like this 1.Bus a.Seat b.Glass a.Blackboard b.Table,but the above example what i given is the required thing,i changed with some other logic also but are not populating the child element.
 I tried iterating like this `{% for field in typelist %}` not giving the desired answer.

Comment: Should it not be type rather than typelist?

Comment: How are these 2 lists related?  Is there a field in `typelist` that ties an item to its parent in `types`?

Comment: @cjd82187 Values for both list are comes from same table

Comment: Can you post the model?

Comment: @Karthikr I tried with typelist,the error is Types' object is not iterable

Comment: @cjd82187 models posted

Comment: Need your view as well, not sure what you are actually passing to those variables.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30839/discussion-between-monk-l-and-cjd82187)

Comment: its still very unclear to me what you are trying to do. Why are you just listing all the types as label ?

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the models i found the answer!

views.py

```
def method(request):
    """"""""""
    typeList = Types.objects.filter(user=user, is_active=True, parent_type_id=None)
        list = []
        for type in typeList:
            if not type.parent_type_id:
                list.append(type)
                subtype = Types.objects.filter(parent_type_id=type.id, is_active=True)
                for subtypes in subtype:
                    list.append(subtypes)
         """"""""
    return render(request, 'some.html',
                  {'typeList':list,})
```

template.html

```
{% for type in typeList%}
    {% if type.parent_type_id == None %}
    <h1>{{type.title}}</h1>
    {% else %}
    <label><input type="checkbox"  {% if type.id in selection %}checked="True" {% endif %} value="{{ type.id }}" name="type_key">{{ type.title }}</label><br />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the view from where you are passing the type and typelist so that we can what are you passing exactly and how are both related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think you should actually have the parent_type_id be a foreign key, but it may still work.

```
{% for type in types %} <h1>{{type.title}}</h1>

   {% for field in typelist %}
    {% if field.parent_type_id == type.id %}
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{field}}">{{ field }}</label><br />
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %} <br />
```

I think for the above to work, your model is going to need to change to something like this:

```
class Types(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    parent_type_id = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Null-able` CharField can not be `None` unless you set it specifically! If you set values through admin or any TextInput, python can not distinct empty-string from `None`, so it will set it as empty-string. [Documentation is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#null)

In your model you define as:

```
parent_type_id = models.CharField('Parent Type', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

And in your views, following will always return an empty QuerySet. So it never executes the `for` loop in your template

```
types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=None)
```

It is better to use `Q` in here

```
from django.db.models import Q

types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, Q(parent_type_id=None|parent_type_id=''))
```